# On leaving the input field Break the jquery loop after giving alert once and

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to match the two fields and check which is the greater value on leaving the input. If the condition is `false`, show the `alert` and break the loop.

However in my code whenever I am typing the keystore its showing me alert. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.rate_cls', function() {
  var rate = parseFloat($("#rate").val());
  var purchase_amount = parseFloat($("#purchase_amount").val());
  if (rate < purchase_amount) {
    alert("check");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rate">
<input type="text" id="purchase_amount">
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated that what i am doing wrong!!

Comment: This is a simple typo - neither of the `input` elements have the `.rate_cls` class. Add that and your code works fine

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "break the loop" - do you mean display the alert only once?  ("whenever I am typing the key it's showing me alert").   You can either add a flag (eg via `data-`) to say the alert has been shown or you can use `.off` to remove the event.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan is right, there is no such element with `.rate_cls` class

Comment: Given OP states the `alert` *is* shown, it's **not a problem with the event handler not being assigned** (and can be put down to copying the code here).

Comment: I forgot to mentioned the class name while entering here

Answer (score 0):

Change .rate_cls to input in the blur event, or add class .rate_cls to the inputs

```js
$(document).on('blur', 'input', function() {
  var rate = parseFloat($("#rate").val());
  var purchase_amount = parseFloat($("#purchase_amount").val());
  if (rate < purchase_amount) {
    alert("check");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rate">
<input type="text" id="purchase_amount">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `rate_cls` on your code. And you are suppose to check when 2nd input got `blur`. And check your inputs are filled.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '#purchase_amount', function() {
  var rate = parseFloat($("#rate").val());
  var purchase_amount = parseFloat($("#purchase_amount").val());
  if (!isNaN(rate) && !isNaN(purchase_amount)) {
    if (rate < purchase_amount) {
      alert("check");
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    alert('fill inputs');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rate">
<input type="text" id="purchase_amount">
```